# Ubuntu 18 Nautilus Folder custom Icon not working

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

In Ubuntu 18 LTS With latest Updates and Unity Desktop, How I can change folder icons in Nautilus?

Currently, nothing happens when I select a new icon in folder Properties. Tried icons 48*48, 64*64 and 512*512 in size and PNG, SVG in format.

The icons I select is in `/usr/share/icons` And `~/Icons` But none of them works and nothing happens after the icon selection.